# What's the conditional variance of the chain X -> Y -> Z?

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability, multivariate-normal-distribution

If I have a cascade of 3 random variables, represented as a Bayesian Graph: $X\rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$, is there a simple formula for $\sigma_{X|Z}$?

Further, assume all the variables are normal, so as part of the graph specification I have $\sigma_{Z|Y}$ and $\sigma_{Y|X}$, could $\sigma_{X|Z}$ be represented in terms of these, and if so, is the assumption of normality important?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no formula for $X|Z$ in terms of $Z|Y$ and $Y|X$, even assuming that all three variables are jointly normal.

For example: If $Y$ is independent of both $X$ and $Z$, then $X$ could be identical with $Z$, with $\sigma_{X|Z}=0$, or independent of $Z$, with $\sigma_{X|Z}=\sigma_X$.

Or: If $Y$ is nearly independent of both $X$ and $Z$, then $X$ could be nearly identical with $Z$, with $\sigma_{X|Z}\simeq 0$, or nearly independent of $Z$, with $\sigma_{X|Z}\simeq \sigma_X$, among many other possibilities.

Comment: This argument leaves one wondering whether independence is a kind of "edge case" where any formula, if it did exist, would necessarily break down.  Thus, it would be nice to see a stronger reason why there cannot be any such formula.

Comment: Interesting argument about $X$ and $Z$ being identical. I would venture in that case the graph as drawn here would be wrong. it would require a direct link between $X$ and $Z$. thoughts?

Comment: As I understand it, the Bayesian graph is mostly used to show our knowledge of a model, and not to constrain a model. I added another paragraph to the answer as an example where the graph is appropriate but it is still clear that no formula would hold.